# Как из PHP вызвать cgi скрипт?

Tags: unix, php

lightsquid cgi скрипт формирует html страничку. Собственно я хочу "перехватить" эту страничку.
Или можно сделать так, из PHP запустить cgi и его результат переправить в файл. А потом этот файл прочитать.

Answer (score 1):

Может тут то, что нужно? [How to run CGI script from PHP](http://www.vbulletin.com/forum/forum/general/php-html-questions/4531-how-to-run-cgi-script-from-php)

или тут [include/execute a CGI file inside a PHP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507979/cant-include-execute-a-cgi-file-inside-a-php-file)

Думаю подойдёт функция [exec](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php)

Comment: Ну да.

       the only answer is that it just cannot or should not be done. Besides, mixing CGI/Perl with PHP is probably not the best practice

Но человеку-то надо. Так что `file_get_contents`

Comment: тогда он получит содержимое скрипта, а не содержимое сформированной им странички.

Comment: @spirit ну-ну-ну.

     $data = file_get_contents("http://fullpathto.cgi",0);

Comment: "file_get_contents — Читает содержимое файла в строку". Эта функция не запустит "http://fullpathto.cgi", а считает его содержимое.

Comment: @spirit, читаем [allow_url_fopen][1]


  [1]: http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php

Comment: P.S. У меня одного сайт жёстко тупит?

Comment: Разве не так "fopen and file_get_contents are nearly equivalent"? Как же тогда считать содержимое .cgi? Да и нужно менять php.ini.

Comment: Да, сайт тупит нереально...
Ну можно не менять .ini, можно это в htaccess прописать, да и потом, на большинстве хостингов это включено.

по поводу fopen: ну там еще надо будет fread, fclose, а file_get_contents просто и сразу получает все содержимое ответа... если файл не очень большой, то этой функцией намного удобнеее пользоваться.